# Removal of multiple trailing slashes after URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm using Apache24, and I recently noticed an issue with the multiple trailing slashes after the URL (I'm not referring to the http:// slashes).

Here's my URL

```
website.com//user/profile:view
```

Which is not displaying the correct page, obviously.

Here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I've tried dozens of other "fixes" but none of them have seemed to work.

How could I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: fix the problem in your sites code rather than trying to band-aid over the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

To remove multiple slashes use this rule **before your existing rule** below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I added the code below "RewriteEngine On" and above the first RewriteCond. The URL still looks like:

http://www.example.com//user/user-action:login/?ref=%2Fhome